# Who should log output, the ThingDoer or the code which calls ThingDoer.DoThing()?

Tags: patterns-and-practices

Here's a common question I ask myself:

If I have a ThingDoer class and it has a method DoThing(), and I want to log a message stating "Doing a thing", should I put this logging code in the ThingDoer.DoThing method, or should I keep this code outside of the method, within the caller?  I feel like there should be some standard principle to follow here but I don't know what it is.

```
Log("Doing Thing");
ThingDoer.DoThing();
```

vs

```
void ThingDoer::DoThing()
{
    Log("Doing Thing");
}
```

Comment: I would say that ideally the logger instance is injected into the `ThingDoer`, so the caller has some control (should it log at all, or not?), and the callee can take care of logging for itself

Comment: I think the really interesting question is: why is it so hard to find a "standard principle" for this situation? Why do we need more context about the involved classes, and which kind of context?

Comment: @DocBrown sheesh, I completely forgot about that answer of mine. Good eye spotting it.

Comment: @candied_orange your answer seems to suggest that you shouldn't do logging in Java (or any language!) since there's no AOP

Comment: @user253751 actually AOP is supported in Java in two different forms. And I'm not saying you shouldn't log. I'm saying it's better if logging code doesn't pollute your class that isn't about logging. Logging is a classic cross cutting concern.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-size fits all answer here. Logging tends to go in the location that can give the appropriate details.

For example, if you don't just want to log that your `Document` is invalid, but you want to log *why* it is invalid, you're going to want the logging to be done by `DocumentValidator` itself, rather than the `DocumentService` which only receives back a boolean from the validator.

On the other hand, if you dig too deep, you lose the context of your call stack. For example, if you really need to know *whose* document failed, `DocumentValidator` might not know that, if it only knows how to handle `Document` objects.
If `DocumentService` has a reference to a `myPerson` (who has a `Documents` property), then the service is the most informed site to write log messages pertaining to both the person and their invalid document.

So it's clear that logging doesn't just belong in one site, it can belong in multiple sites. So how do you implement this? There are several ways of doing it:

- At a very basic level, you could have a statically available logger that everyone can access.
- At a more advanced level, you could pass a logger down through the methods, so that all involved dependencies can write their own messages into the same logger.
- Your objects can define their own logger in their constructor and each write to their own logger.
- You could rely on DI and an IoC container to inject your loggers for you.

It won't surprise you that there are multiple ways of achieving the same thing, so it's a matter of looking for what suits you best. There are cases where I prefer the ability to pass a single logger between a few dependencies (i.e. so that logger can encapsulate all those messages in a unique location), but it's more common to simply have each class log to their own log.

This depends on the technology you want to use, and the kind of software you're building. I use completely different logging libraries based on the type of project I'm working on.

Comment: This is very similar to my own thinking here. And again, the usual careless downvoters seem to be around here, who apparently think we all should be able to read their minds why they downvoted this answer. Sure, the question is a duplicate, but the accepted answer to that other question (despite being upvoted by at least 11 members, including me) lacks some practical applicability for many projects.